# Using $http.get to retrieve from API(zendesk) not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, curl

I'm trying to make an API call to [Zendesk's API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/introduction) and I keep getting a 401 auth code even though the same thing works when I do a cURL in terminal. How can I make this work in Angular?

```
function dataservice($http) {
    var service = {
        getMacros: getMacros
    };

    return service;
    /////////////////////

    function getMacros() {

        var client = {
           username: window.btoa('myEmail'),
           token: window.btoa('/token:myToken'),
           remoteUri: 'https://myCompany.zendesk.com/api/v2/macros.json'
        };

        console.log('Loading...');
        return $http({
               method: 'GET',
               url: client.remoteUri,
               headers: {
                   'Authorization': client.username + client.token
              }
            })                
            .then(getMacrosComplete)
            .catch(function (message) {
                exception.catcher('Failed to getMacros')(message);
            });

        function getMacrosComplete(response) {
            console.log('Done');
            var data = response.data;
            return data;
        };
    };
```

The code above always returns a 401 while this works:

```
curl myEmail/token:myToken https://myCompany.zendesk.com/api/v2/macros.json
```

Seems to work well. Probably something obvious.

Comment: Try adding "withCredentials: true" to your $http configuration object. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Comment: Also, I don't think your curl request is sending an authorization header...maybe client.user + client.token needs to be passed in the request body instead?

Comment: Pretty sure the value of your `Authorization` header is wrong … The username and password have to be concatenated with a colon (`:`), and then the resulting string has to be base64 encoded – not the individual parts.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you need to set Authorization headers properly, they should be Base64 encoded and you have to state "Basic" authentication (this is the main part most people miss).

So this should work:

```js
function dataservice($http) {
    var service = {
        getMacros: getMacros
    };

    return service;
    /////////////////////

    function getMacros() {

        var client = {
           username: 'myEmail',
           token: 'myToken',
           remoteUri: 'https://myCompany.zendesk.com/api/v2/macros.json'
        };

        console.log('Loading...');
        return $http({
               method: 'GET',
               url: client.remoteUri,
               headers: {
                   'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(client.username + '/token:' + client.token)
              }
            })                
            .then(getMacrosComplete)
            .catch(function (message) {
                exception.catcher('Failed to getMacros')(message);
            });

        function getMacrosComplete(response) {
            console.log('Done');
            var data = response.data;
            return data;
        };
    };
```

Of course you have to have token authentication enabled in your Zendesk account, otherwise you can authenticate via user + password by setting up a password instead and doing:

```js
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(client.username + ':' + client.password)
```